# A word is not allowed to ask here

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary, spoken-english, word-in-context

Guess this question will be closed soon. But, I still need to figure out what it means in the context of a garage sale. Is "hard-xxx" negative or positive in the clip, "You are such a little "hard-xxx"? The boy seems happy, but how about the man? What does he mean when using such a word?  [Here the link](https://sendvid.com/xwm98m3o).

Comment: The word hard-*** is an insulting (negative) term. It is an informal and impolite word for a tough and unyielding person. The boy seems happy due to making a sale not for being called a hard-***. The man is not happy with the boy due to which he used this insulting term for the boy. On a side note, you should look up a word in a dictionary (Merriam-Webster, Dictionary.com, etc.) before asking.

Comment: This the Internet, not a church. You're allowed to use bad words here, *especially* if you're talking about the bad word itself and its usage. I imagine the word you're talking about is **hard-ass** but I don't know because you censored yourself.

Comment: Actually, this is a particular place on the internet, and yeah, not all of us love reading profanities. So I applaud you for having some self-control, OP. I wish more native speakers had that. Now, the man is unhappy; he is using an insulting term. He's not complimenting the boy. The boy is smiling because he got away with it.

Comment: @FeliniusRex As long as the vulgar word isn’t in the title without a fig leaf, it’s fine to include it in the body. When it comes to education, it is not admirable to censor questions. Native English speakers may be able to suss out what those Xs stand for, but this question is useless to some one searching for [hard-ass](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hard-ass) or a learner who doesn’t know the word. This question is entirely answerable with a dictionary and should be closed.

Comment: @FeliniusRex The place for these discussions is on [meta] not here, see https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5100/9161 The policy is to keep vulgar language out of the title but for clarity allow it to be spelled out in the body of it’s not gratuitous. Readers should not have to follow a link to a file of unknown origin that may disappear tomorrow to understand a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard-xxx is a synonym for stubborn in this situation. At a garage sale, the price of items isn’t exactly set; you can bargain it in your favor. The use of hard-xxx is kind of a backhanded compliment. The man is jokingly angry that a kid got an extra dollar out of him, and the kid is happy that he made an extra dollar through his stubbornness. Usually, a hard-xxx would be a insult, but they were only joking.

Comment: Would it be so difficult to just write hard-ass? It is a back-handed compliment but probably not one the kid would understand....

Comment: @Lambie 'probably not one the kid would understand....' - you'd be surprised what kids understand these days.

Comment: @Shotsphere That's why I asked this question. I wondered if the man was just kidding. Otherwise, he wouldn't ask the boy to keep the change, would he?